Cheap Motion Activated Cameras
I am looking for two, cheap cameras for temporary use in Australia / NZ

Cheap - ideally less than  $100
Mains (220-230V) powered - ideally plug into a socket
WIfi for connection
Motion activated - Ideally start streaming on motion
Stream remotely to Android or Windows
I have a local windows laptop that could be used, but I prefer not to.

There's this question but it seems to have answers for Weather station linked cameras only.  I don't have weather stations.

I'm using old smartphones with "AlfredCamera" if that's an option. They always stream, and record clips on movement which are saved for 7 days in the free plan.
